# Foreach loop, tasks and DataGridViewRows within a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach, task

I am currently trying to start a new tasks for each row within a DataGrid. The code I currently have for this is below:-

```
ArrayList tasks = new ArrayList();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblProduct.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewRow rowCopy = row;
    Task newTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        checkRow(rowCopy);
    });

    tasks.Add(newTask);
    newTask.Start();   
}
```

The  problem is, it skips to the end and stops before it has gone through every row. What can be done to allow a task to be run for each row?

***EDIT***

Tested the loop without the Task and it works as expected. Unsure as to why it does not work when the Tasks are being started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably is asking about:

`Task.WaitAll(tasks);` *after* the end of the loop

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblProduct.Rows)
{
    ...
    tasks.Add(newTask);
    ..   
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I have `Task.WaitAll((Task[])tasks.ToArray(typeof(Task)))` after the foreach loop and the problem still persists.

Comment: So, they may be completed *that* fast that to you it looks like they never ran. Are you sure that `checkRow` is *not* called for every row, as you expected ?

Comment: I have an output being written to the console everytime the `checkRow` is ran. When the task is not there and it is running synchronously, it produces an output for each row in the table. However, when it is inside a task, only around 20 outputs are produced from a table that contains 700 different rows. One of the outputs from this is always the last row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has been answered correctly, but for future readers, problem here was the the `checkRow` is being updated before the tasks can do anything, then, the last value for checkRow is what tasks really use. To avoid this, don't use the same variable for all tasks, instead call those not shared vars like this:

```
ArrayList tasks = new ArrayList();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblProduct.Rows)

        {

            Task newTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                DataGridViewRow rowCopy = row;
                checkRow(rowCopy);
            });

            tasks.Add(newTask);
            newTask.Start();   
        }
```

Or, just use `parallel.foreach` and not tasks